# How to naming namespaces for product that have sub-products/modules?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces, using

I read that carefully. And yes very helpful!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces

Assuming you have following products and namespaces

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory     is a DLL
Microsoft.Dynamics.Bank          is a DLL
```

Each of above have (Views, Reports, Utils, etc)

**Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.DLL**

Should I go for that?

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Sales.Reports
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Sales.Views
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Sales.Controls

Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Purchase.Reports
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Purchase.Views
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Purchase.Controls
```

**Or** Go for that?  *(Currently used)*

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Reports.Sales
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Views.Sales
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Controls.Sales

Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Reports.Purchase
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Views.Purchase
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Controls.Purchase
```

When you write `using directives` the first one appears good. But the folder structures will be bad.

1. If I use second approach I got very good structured folders [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wdzW.png)
2. If I use first approach each Sub-Module have Views, Reports, Controls (Duplicated)

Please its not opinion based. I actually afraid for a bad structured later will become worse.

I can't imagine an example with `System.Data.SqlClient` are not `System.SqlClient.Data` alright?

Usually

```
System.Data.Common can used bellow
System.Data.OleDb
System.Data.SqlClient
System.Data.AnyProvider
```

**How to apply that structure to My example above?**

**Notes**

1. A Sales maybe doesn't have Reports (So are first approach bad?)
2. A Purchase maybe doesn't have controls (So are first approach bad?)

I see that in MVC architecture they go with second approach. I don't sure about that.

https://github.com/cruzerM/erp-bank-net/tree/master/ERP_BANK.Web/Views

**So should I fllow second approach?**

Comment: If the answer can solve your issue, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the objects in those classes are similar then try this approach

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Reports
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Views
Microsoft.Dynamics.Inventory.Controls
```

In these object,  Use something called TransactionType indicating if its a purchase or sales.